# How to use docker inside Alpine/Any docker image in gitlab ci

Tags: docker, dockerfile, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

> I want to build and test my app using dockerfile located in other private repository.
> For that I'm using Alpine official docker image in which i run a bash script for cloning my private repo and running docker for building the docker image. This is how my `.gitlab-ci.yml` looks like.

```
    image: alpine:3.15
stages:
  - main

main-job:
  stage: main
  script:
    - apk add --update docker openrc
    - rc-update add docker boot
    - apk add bash git curl
    - bash build.sh $GH_TOKEN $REPO
```

And I have simple script in `build.sh`

```
git clone https://${GH_TOKEN}@github.com/${REPO} source
cd source || exit 1
docker container prune --force || true
docker build . --rm --force-rm --compress --no-cache=true --pull --file Dockerfile -t test-app
docker image ls
docker run --privileged --rm -i test-app
```

But Docker don't start and spams error.

```
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

> Also tried with other command in ubuntu docker like `service start docker` , `dockerd`, `service restart docker` and others.
> But nothing seems to works as i guess we can't run docker inside a docker or something.

**Can we have any alternative idea to it?**

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you don’t have a docker agent running. You can use the docker in docker service by adding the following:

```yaml
services:
  - docker:dind
```

See the GitLab-ci docs on building docker images for more info: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html

Comment: ```Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?.
See 'docker run --help'.
``` 
Still facing the same issue, can you help me with full code?

Comment: Also I'm using alpine as image.

Answer (score 0):

I've meet the same issue. May be you have to permit gitlab-runner on your host.

```
sudo usermod -aG docker gitlab-runner
```

Comment: I'm using some public hosted gitlab-runner, so not in my hand to do so.

Answer (score -1):

I‘d suggest you build and push your built image to dockerhub. Then you can start the container referencing your prebuilt image.

Comment: I thought same, but there is some other workaround or hack to it? I kept this option for last . I'm saying that because my dockerfile is not perfect and have to make changes on regular basis. Also while testing i do multiple changes a day and might be hectic manageing it on schedule too.

Comment: The other way to do it would be to use docker compose. This would allow you to take the alpine image and run git commands in the image itself to pull the project, build it in there and then run the image right away with the project already built and set up.

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: I‘m a bit confused why you need to run docker in docker. You already seem to have docker locally that could build your image. Why do you want to build the image in a docker container rather on your system itself?

Comment: I need it because I have to host my app on other hosting service.